# Multilanguage parsing in python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a bunch of tweets stored in a database, and now I need to create a search engine to find a particular tweet, so I am trying to create an inverse index of all the tweets.

Such process requires parsing of the tweets, which, for most languages, might be simple: you just break up the sentence at the spaces. But for some languages where people generally do not use spaces to separate the words, such as Chinese and Japanese, it would become tedious. And worst of all, a significant number of the tweets are multilingual, for example the following tweet:

> 青空だ♪ (@ 成田国際空港 第1ターミナル (Narita International Airport - Terminal 1) w/ 3 others) http://t.co/eqjJSxTX

In this circumstance I will need to convert the above string into a tuple using python:

> ("青","空","だ","♪","(@","成","田","国","際","空","港","","第","1","タ","ー","ミ","ナ","ル","(","Narita","International","Airport","-","Terminal","1)","w/","3","others)","http://t.co/eqjJSxTX")

That is, for Japanese characters, each element should contain only one character, but for non-Japanese characters, parsing of the string should go by spaces.

So is there any available library to carry out this function, or if such a library does not exist, what is a relatively simple way of achieving this?

Thank you all.

Comment: Why does the '(' that start 'Narita' get it's one string but the one that ends 'others' doesn't?

Comment: Just some noob spitballing here,wouldn't codecs help you convert them to unicode and then you could handle them rite?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find some insights regarding CJK languages here:

http://plone.org/products/cjksplitter-chinese-japanese-korean-word-splitter-for-zctextindex

I believe, this will solve the searchability problems for CJK languages.

Also, there is a Python library:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cjklib/

Answer (score -1):

Try [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
words = regex.findall(ur'([\p{Han}\p{Katakana}]|[\p{Latin}\p{Number}]+)', tweet)
```

(this assumes "tweet" to be Unicode, if it isn't, convert it first).